# Why CMD ask me, if the target is a file or folder?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, mkdir

I've searching currently lots of time on the web, but i don't find the answer.

I'm creating a folder, if not exists.

```
set CUR_DIR="%CD%"
set NAME_SOURCE="Source"
set NAME_BUILD="Build"

if not exist %CUR_DIR%\%NAME_BUILD% md "%CUR_DIR%\%NAME_BUILD%\"
```

But when i try to execute it, a prompt will stop the routine:

> Does D:\test\Build specify a file name or directory name on the target
>   (F = file, D = directory)?

How i can fix this "issue"? I've tried to add a directory seperator on end and/or add quotes.

Comment: Cannot reproduce...?

Comment: never seen `mkdir` produce a message like this (and why should it ask for file? it's "make directory") I know `copy` some files will produce exactly this message.

Comment: I suspect the actual script is larger, and the message comes from the part we aren't shown. Try creating a [mcve].

Comment: Somewhere you are using `XCOPY`  to copy a single file (which is not seen in the code). you can use `echo f|XOPY....`

Comment: @Stephan - not copy but xcopy.

Comment: use `xcopy "<source>" "<destination>\"` to make clear you mean a folder name.

Comment: …and similarly, whilst you're at it, change `if not exist %CUR_DIR%\%NAME_BUILD% md "%CUR_DIR%\%NAME_BUILD%\"` to `if not exist "%CUR_DIR%\%NAME_BUILD%\" md "%CUR_DIR%\%NAME_BUILD%"`.